# Why doesn't `OpenSSL::Pkey::RSA.new` prompt for a missing password in JRuby?

Tags: ruby, openssl, rubygems, jruby, private-key

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to make JRuby prompt for a missing password (as MRI Ruby does)
when `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new` is called without a password.

For example, given this script:

```
# example.rb
require 'openssl'

def test pemkey_text, pemkey_pass
  puts "Decrypting key using password #{pemkey_pass.inspect}"
  begin
    key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new pemkey_text, pemkey_pass
    puts "success"
  rescue OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError => e
    puts %(failure: #{e.message}\n\t#{e.backtrace.join("\n\t")})
  end
end

pemkey_text = DATA.read
pemkey_pass = "correct horse battery staple"

test pemkey_text, pemkey_pass
test pemkey_text, nil

__END__
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,40D5A4CB36A82BF11E864AB17F4796BF
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If I run it with MRI Ruby, it prompts for a password during the second `test`:

```
% rvm use ruby-2.1
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5
% ruby example.rb
Decrypting key using password "correct horse battery staple"
success
Decrypting key using password nil
Enter PEM pass phrase:
success
```

However, if I run it with JRuby, the second `test` raises an error instead
of prompting the user for a password:

```
% rvm use jruby
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16.1
% ruby example.rb
Decrypting key using password "correct horse battery staple"
success
Decrypting key using password nil
failure: Neither PUB key nor PRIV key:
        org/jruby/ext/openssl/PKeyRSA.java:281:in `initialize'
        example.rb:6:in `test'
        example.rb:17:in `(root)'
```

I'm wondering if this is because some combination of my install of java/openssl/jruby/jruby_openssl, but none
of the various permutations of alternate installs have succeeded, so I'm beginning to wonder
if there's a way to make this work at all.

And if you want to know why I don't just prompt for the password myself, it's because I'm trying
to use `rubygems` `gem` command, which [doesn't include a way to pass it the private key password currently](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/05c29680e515c000552008f725747261ffa6008d/lib/rubygems/request.rb#L56).

Comment: The jruby openssl library is a completely different implementation (that uses bouncy castle rather than openssl) so I suppose it's not entirely surprising there are some differences (although it may be unintentional)

Comment: This looks very much like [JRUBY-6622](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6622). There, the devs report it should work with JRuby 1.7.18. If not, please open an issue at https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/.

Comment: Generally, it is probably a good idea to test the latest version of JRuby (currently 1.7.19) and jruby-openssl (currently 0.9.6).

Comment: Holger Just: yup, the error persists when tested against JRuby-1.7.19 and JRuby-1.7.18 with jruby-openssl 0.9.6.  I'll open an issue.

Comment: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/2697

Comment: for next time please report issues at https://github.com/jruby/jruby-openssl/issues